# I have four layers

Tags: riddle

> As in an onion, I have layers.
>
> My first layer is usually calm but has been known to have a few rough edges.
>
> My second layer is hard to read, constantly changing: I can be unpredictable.
>
> My third and my fourth layer share a common interest.

Comment: Shrek reference:P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> the Earth?

The four layers are:

> the crust, the mantel, the outer core and the inner core.
>  The crust has rough edges.
>  The mantel is constantly moving fluid.
>  And the inner and outer core have the same use.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is:

> The Earth. The earth has layers like an onion

My first layer is usually calm but has been known to have a few rough edges.

> The crust. Usually calm, except for occasional earthquakes, rough edges could refer to land.

My second layer is hard to read, constantly changing: I can be unpredictable.

> The liquid mantle. Very viscous, constantly moves over long time periods and is unpredictable. Causes movement of tectonic plates.

My third and my fourth layer share a common interest.

> Inner and outer core. Both very dense layers, made up primarily of iron and nickel.

Answer (score 7):

Another answer -

You are a

> Burger :)

Explanation

> **Layer 1** - *Cheese* with rough edges
>  **Layer 2** - *Fillings/Toppings*. Often it's difficult to know what stuff's are included in a burger. They keep changing according to what kind of burger you are eating.
>  **Layer 3 & 4** - *Bun* which serves same purpose

Here's an example -

> [image]

Comment: nice , but i think layers should be in order ...here it is jumbled

Comment: @AmruthA Looks better now ;)

Comment: @Techidiot but a burger isn't spherical?

Comment: @Techidiot I think layer one should come first..Not 4

Comment: @Jason_ Since there is nothing mentioned about the order of layers, I have considered and named in this order.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Not sure if "spherical" is mentioned any where :)

Comment: "As in an onion" The question disagrees. An onion has spherical layers.